# How to add an overbrace on top of a table in beamer?

Tags: tables

I have written following code for a table in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for bold italic

\usecolortheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.20mm}
    \begin{picture}(400,250)
    \put(50,0){\line(1,0){525}}
    \put(50,50){\line(1,0){525}}
    \put(50,100){\line(1,0){525}}
    \put(50,0){\line(0,1){100}}
    \put(200,0){\line(0,1){100}}    
    \put(250,0){\line(0,1){100}}
    \put(375,0){\line(0,1){100}}
    \put(425,0){\line(0,1){100}}
    \put(575,0){\line(0,1){100}}
    \put(90,25){\color{black} Users }
    \put(215,25){\color{black} 10 }
    \put(260,25){\color{black} 1234500 }
    \put(390,25){\color{black} 450}
    \put(460,25){\color{black} Users  }
    \put(70,75){\color{blue} First Section }
    \put(215,75){\color{black} AA }
    \put(260,75){\color{magenta} BB }
    \put(390,75){\color{black} ZZ }
    \put(440,75){\color{blue} Last Section }
    \end{picture}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to draw an overbrace from the left edge of AA cell to the right edge of ZZ cell. How can I go about. I also want to write some text above the overbrace.

Comment: @Bernard Showing following error on my system                                                                                                 Package auto-pst-pdf Error: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need a `picture` environment to make a table. I propose to have a  plain `tabular` environment, and use `pstricks` to have an overbracket (which will look nicer than an overbrace, in my opinion) with some text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for bold italic
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{10pt}
\usecolortheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering\makegapedcells%\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{postscript}
    \begin{tabular}{| *{5}{c|}}
      \hline
      \color{blue} First Section & \pnode(0,20pt){A}AA & \color{magenta} BB & ZZ\pnode(0,20pt){Z} & \color{blue} Last Section \\
      \hline
      Users & 10 & 1234500 & 450 & Users \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \ncbar[angle=90, linewidth=0.4pt, arm=1ex]{A}{Z}\naput{some text}
  \end{postscript}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]